# PHP/SQL Trying to get all order numbers where status = something and put order number into array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I'm working on a Kitchen Display Screen. I have it working if I know the order numbers. I'm trying to get all of the order numbers where status = "INQUEUE" and put those numbers into an array. The goal is to have a count of the total "INQUEUE" orders as well as have the segments on the screen only show arr[0]-Arr[4]. For some reason this section of code causes an error.

```
    $status= "INQUEUE";    
    $arr    = array();
    $sql    = "select ORDID from HEADERS where CurrentStatus=$status";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());  
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
      $arr[] = $row[ORDID];
    }
```

I'm hoping to grab all of the order numbers that have a status of "INQUEUE" into the array, so I can display the orders as arr[X]

Comment: First off, `mysql_*` family of functions is deprecated in PHP5.5 ( or 5.6 cant remember ) and it's removed in PHP7+.  So if your learning I would look at either `mysqli` or `PDO`.  PDO is the better of the two, but requires more knowledge of Object Oriented Programing.  And learn how to use PREPARED STATEMENTS <please>.  That said what is this `ORDID` the way you have it will be seen as a constant, you want `$row["ORDID"]` in place of that.

Comment: PS.  PDO would allow you to fetch the result as an array for that column. `$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 1)` if I recall right., and allow you to skip the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the specific error you are receiving?

One thing that stands out on the query is the variable needs to be enclosed within single quotes so it looks like this:

```
$sql    = "select ORDID from HEADERS where CurrentStatus='$status'";
```

Sometimes when I'm working with dynamically-built queries I like to echo out the query string so I can see exactly how it's being sent to the server.

Also, it's always a good idea to get in the habit of using prepared statements with parameterized queries when working with dynamically-built SQL queries.

Also, in agreement with ArtisticPhoenix, I recommend porting over to another library. Finally, make sure the array index descriptor is enclosed in double quotes. Here's your code using mysqli:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("dbserver", "user", "password", "database");
$status= "INQUEUE";    
$arr    = array();
$sql    = "select ORDID from HEADERS where CurrentStatus='$status'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);  
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $arr[] = $row["ORDID"];
}
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work using    $result = $conn->query($sql); instead of    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Interesting. I've never used the 'or die(MySQL_error());' method before so I don't have a good answer there as to why.

Comment: It helped get something to show up! I'm still not capturing ORDID in the array. I tried it with quotes too when inserting it into the array.

Comment: Silly question, but is the query valid? Have you tried it against the database using MyPHPAdmin or directly from the MySQL server itself? I also agree with ArtisticPhoenix in using a different library. I've had good experience with mysqli and it would be easy to port your code to use it.

Comment: Yep! It gets the one ORDID with that status.

Comment: One more dumb question... How are you examining your array to test if it received any results?

Comment: They're not dumb questions. I'm nowhere near a pro.   I'm using print_r($arr);
which just prints   array()   and I'm also using

$ordernum= $arr[0];   to show an order in the first box. It works if I set $ordernum to 166, which is the only ORDID with status INQUEUE, which shows up if ran in phpmyadmin, but it shows nothing, so I'm assuming the array is empty.

Comment: I don't want to insult your intelligence, but sometimes many times it's the obvious stuff that stumps me. Print_r is the function to use, so we can be confident it's empty. Have you tried using mysqli for giggles?

Comment: On the array descriptor on $row, enclose ORDID in doubles quotes (see my updated answer)

Comment: I had it in quotes. PEBCAC for sure. It worked with mysqli. I need to teach myself mysqli or PDO like you and the other guy mentioned. Thanks. I spent several hours on that.